# Using Cauchy Integral Formula for $ \oint \frac{\cos(z)}{z(z^2+8)} $ on curve |z| =2

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Since
$$
(z^2+8) = (z+\sqrt{8}i)(z-\sqrt{8}i)
$$
For Cauchy's formula $ \frac{1}{2i\pi}\oint\frac{f(z)}{z-w} dz $ I can say that
$$
f(z) = \frac{cos(z)}{z(z+\sqrt{8}i)}
$$
and denominator is $$ (z-\sqrt{8}i)$$ with $w=\sqrt{8}i$

Hence:
$$
f(w) = f(\sqrt{8}i) = \frac{cos(\sqrt{8}i)}{16}
$$
Therefore the original integral would be equal to:
$$
 \oint \dfrac{cos(z)}{z(z^2+8)} = \frac{\pi i cos(\sqrt{8}i)}{8}
$$
But this seems to be wrong...

Comment: Just remember you need to to enclose your work with dollar signs (\$ ... \$), and that  $\cos x$ needs a backlash in front (\$\cos x\$).

Comment: corrected. Thank you.

Comment: The only pole is at $z=0$ and is a simple order 1 pole of strength $\frac18$.  so why is this not just equal to $2\pi i /8$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function $f$ is not analytic in $|z| <2$ so Cauchy's Integral Formula is not applicable. Take $f(z)=\frac {\cos \, z} {z^{2}+8}$ instead. The integral is $2\pi i f(0)=2\pi i /8$.

Comment: I don' understand why you can just take away the $\frac{1}{z}$ ... ?

Comment: @NapoleonCornejo $f(0)=\frac 1 {2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac {f(z)} {z-0} dz$. This is by Cauchy's Integral Formula.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments the only pole is at $z=0$.  The residue is $\frac18$.  By the residue theorem we get $\frac{\pi i}4$.

To use Cauchy's integral formula,  note the integral equals $\oint_{\mid z\mid =2}\dfrac{f(z)}z$, where $f(z)=\dfrac{\cos z}{z^2+8}$.